# How does FileInputStream algorithm works?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

how bytes created by `FileInputStream` class are created?
example if file contain number 12 read by `FileInputStream`, generated bytes are [49, 50, 13, 10], why?

```
import java.io.*;
public class exp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            is = new FileInputStream(new File("./info.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){}
        while(true){
            byte b = 0;
            try{
                b = (byte) is.read();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            if(b == -1) break;
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

`12` as 32-bit in binary `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001100`

bytes should be `[0, 0, 0, 12]` instead of `[49, 50, 13, 10]`.

Comment: Understand that you're not transmitting the number itself, but rather its text representation and are reading from and transmitting text, including the asci char code for "1", "2", and line feeds.

Comment: This is because the `12` is just a text. `1` and `2` in ASCII are 49 and 50, and the new line character and carriage return character are also included in the file, having ASCII codes 10 and 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ASCII.

```
49 == '1'
50 == '2'
13 == '\r' //carriage return
10 == '\n' //end of line
```

It's because the file is a text file and not a binary file. Everything is correct, if the file was written on a Linux machine it would make only four characters.